# TESTBED.inject Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, continuous-integration

I want to test an angular service that injects a script into angular components or page document

this is my service:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class NgxToolsLoadService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}

  load(
    src: string,
  ): void {

 let el = this.document.createElement('script');
 el.src=sec;
 this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
    
  }
}
```

and this is my jest.config

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  onlyChanged: true,
  collectCoverage: false,
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "types"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest",
  },

};
```

I tried changing `testEnvironment` to jsdom, but I got an error: `Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test` and this code didn't help

```
jest.setTimeout(100000);
jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
```

now I'm using `testEnvironment: node`

however, these are my test trials

```
// myservice.service.spec.ts

import { test, expect, afterAll, beforeEach, jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyService} from './myservice.service';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

let service: MyService;

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [MyService, { provide: Document, useExisting: DOCUMENT }],
  });
  service= TestBed.inject(MyService);
});

test('service should be created', () => {
  expect(ngxToolsLoadService).toBeTruthy();
});
```

the test fails and the service couldn't be created
and I got this error

```
ReferenceError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[NgxToolsLoadService -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgxToolsLoadService -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]: 
        document is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using [jest-preset-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-preset-angular) instead of [ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest) in `jest.config.js` file